# Creating a voidstick zombie

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, undead

I'm playing a necromancer in a game and a common issue is that I only have access to low HD corpses. During research into improving my matrials I came across a [Voidstick](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/voidstick/) which can be used to create [voidstick zombies](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/zombie/zombie-voidstick), which are vastly stronger than anything else I have at 15HD.

Since it seems to create a specific undead, the original hosts ability scores do not matter. There seem to be two ways to perform the ritual. One requires an hour long ritual and a corpse which finishes with a DC25 knowledge religion check. The second only requires a helpless living and them failing a save.

The problem I'm having is with

> To fully animate the creature, one voidstick must be used for each Hit Die the base creature has

When it says base creature, is it talking about the body you are using, or is it talking about the final result? Because if its the body it makes much more sense to use lv1 NPC's (conveniently stocked at any nearby village) instead of using 15. Paying 2500 gp for a single voidstick zombie is an amazing deal, but 37500 gp is not such a great deal. At that price I dont even know if it would be worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term **base creature** typically refers to the creature absent the template that's to be applied. A [skeleton](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeleton/), for instance, "uses all the base creature’s statistics and special abilities except as noted here." The same should go for the [voidstick zombie](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/zombie/zombie-voidstick), a commoner 1 requiring but a lone [*voidstick*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/voidstick) to animate it as a voidstick zombie.

Note that the description of the *voidstick* says, "Undead created using voidsticks are not under the control of their creator but can be commanded using channeled negative energy, spells, or similar effects." In other words, be careful what you animate—sometimes dead is better.

Comment: I planned on creating the zombie with the "Talisman, Death’s Head" or rely on other means of control. But yes, this creation could be dangerous.

Comment: Are you saying that the end result should be a 1HD voidstick zombie using the commoner?

Comment: @Fering Voidstick zombie isn't a template, but templates are what typically use the base creature language—that's for comparison. You'd end up with a regular ol' voidstick zombie. (And *voidsticks* seem pretty nuts—run those by your GM first!)

Comment: I was just making sure. Its always best to verify things. Yes, these items and all I plan on doing with them will have to be passed by the GM first. Im hoping to also apply the bloody template so that if they are killed, they will just come back.

Comment: Nevermind, bloody is a skeleton template, not zombie